# Is this Easter egg/reference really in Pokémon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I was looking at Easter eggs and references and I read [this IGN Article](http://au.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-x-y/Easter_Eggs_and_References) which stated:

> The characters' father
>
> In the games over the years except Sapphire and Ruby the player never gets to see the father of their character however in Pokémon X if the female character is dressed in this outfit Black felt hat, Little black dress, black tights, bow shoes/Mary Jane's black, black strappy purse, black hat ribbon, black hair, eye colour and length of hair doesn't matter, then when she goes back to her home if she sits on her bed on the space closest to her pillows then you will see a tear fall down her eye and instead of dripping onto her clothes it stays as a bubble of water.

Is this real? This was the only place I saw/read it.

Can someone confirm, preferably with proof?

Answer (score 4):

The page was likely vandalized. Recent editors performed some rollbacks and it no longer has the "Easter Egg" you mention. The Easter Egg was not real.

---

### Original Answer

The page has likely simply been vandalized. I cannot find any other references to this supposed Easter Egg. The quote you reference was added in the most recent revision to the page, unlike most of the other Easter Eggs, it includes no screenshots or other evidence.

It is not really possible to prove something doesn't exist, the onus is them to prove that the Easter Egg exists.

Another "Easter Egg" on the same page, made in the revision before the one you cite.

> in pokemon XY has a easter egg (the old version) where the pokemon is targeted CreepyPastas is DISCO STRANGE Porygon EVIL !!!